# How to print multiple lines to a .txt file (external) in Java?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java programming so this might be a noob question, but I have developed a movie ticket reservation program for a coursework of mine and one of the requirements for it is to allow the user to print out a receipt for the purchase. I have succeeded in getting to print the output to the .txt file but the problem is that all the information prints in a single line but I want them to print in different lines. Can someone please help me out with this?

```
 private void printReceiptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        showMessageDialog(this, "Your receipt is printing!");

        //print receipt to a text file called Receipt
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Receipt.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        //calculation of prices
        float adultPrice = (float) (countA * 9.00);
        float studentPrice = (float) (countSt * 8.00);
        float seniorPrice = (float) (countSe * 7.00);
        float childPrice = (float) (countC * 5.00);

        //total price for tickets
        float totalPrice = adultPrice + studentPrice + seniorPrice + childPrice;

        try {
            String queryString = "SELECT title, movietheatre FROM movies WHERE movieid = " + movieID;
            ResultSet results = myStatement.executeQuery(queryString);

            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (results.next()) {
                strBuilder.append("\t Cinema Ticket Receipt");
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Movie Title : ").append(results.getString(1));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Time : ").append(time);
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Date : ").append(date);
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Movie Hall : ").append(results.getString(2));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Adult ticket price : ").append(formatter.format(adultPrice));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Student ticket price : ").append(formatter.format(studentPrice));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Seniors ticket price : ").append(formatter.format(seniorPrice));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Children ticket price : ").append(formatter.format(childPrice));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("\n");
                strBuilder.append("Total price : £").append(formatter.format(totalPrice));
                strBuilder.append("\n");
            }                             
            results.close();
            //String formatStr = strBuilder.toString();
            //out.write(String.format(formatStr));


            pw.print(strBuilder.toString());
            pw.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println(sqle);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Receipt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    showMessageDialog(this, "Receipt printing complete.");
}
```

Comment: What is the output? Why do you think its printing on same line?

Comment: Don't use `"\n"` but rather the line terminator for that OS

Comment: `String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: And hint: you do everything in one method. Dont do that! Create a method that fetches data from the DB, and maybe maybe turns that into a string. Then write a method that writes strings into files.

Comment: The output comes to a text file called Receipt but when I open it, all of the information is coming in a single line rather than multiple lines.

Comment: Right, and when you append a line separator in place of `"\n"` -- what happens?

Comment: And where should I use line.seperateor? I'm sorry but I don't know how that works...

Comment: It's common sense. You get the String like I show above, and put that String everywhere you're currently using `"\n"`.

Comment: do you mean to say not to use \n and just use append?

Comment: oh okay. I will try that and see then.

Comment: Thank you!! The "line.seperator" worked! :)

Comment: Of course it did.